# I want to add custom floating spinner

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to add custom floating spinner. How to add like this ?? 
I have tried with AutoComplete textview inside TextInputLayout but it's not properly worked.
http://prntscr.com/mm8ksc

```
//SocietySpinnerLayout.axml
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:id="@+id/societySpinnerLayout"
                    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorText"
                    android:theme="@style/CommonTextStyleTheme">
                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                            android:id="@+id/societySpinner"
                            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_20"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#4C5375"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_14"
                            android:hint="SOCIETY"
                            android:paddingEnd="60dp"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:inputType="textPhonetic" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

//SocietySpinner.cs

     private void BindToMySociety()
            {
                //String[] arraySociety = Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.arraySociety);

                ArrayAdapter adapter = new SpinnerSocietyAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.PublisherSpinnerItemLayout, HelperNavigation.LstSociety);
                _societySpinner.Adapter = adapter;
                if (_societySpinner.HasFocus)
                {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                    imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Window.CurrentFocus.WindowToken, 0);
                }
               _societySpinner.SetOnTouchListener(this);
                _societySpinner.Focusable = false;
                // _societySpinner.Click+=_societySpinner_Click;
                _societySpinner.ItemClick += _societySpinner_ItemClick;
                _societySpinner.SetOnDismissListener(this);
                if(_selectedSociety!=null)
                {
                    _societySpinner.Text = _selectedSociety.name;
                }
            }

        private void _societySpinner_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // _societySpinner.Text = string.Empty;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_societySpinner.Text))
                {
                    _societySpinner.Text = string.Empty;
                    _societySpinnerLayout.Typeface = ItalicFont;
                    _societySpinner.Typeface = ItalicFont;
                }
              ((AutoCompleteTextView)_societySpinner).ShowDropDown();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            try
            {
                // _societySpinner.Text = string.Empty;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_societySpinner.Text))
                {
                    _societySpinner.Text = string.Empty;
                    _societySpinnerLayout.Typeface = ItalicFont;
                    _societySpinner.Typeface = ItalicFont;
                }
                ((AutoCompleteTextView)v).ShowDropDown();
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        public void OnDismiss()
        {
            if(_selectedSociety!=null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedSociety.name))
                {
                    _societySpinner.Text = _selectedSociety.name;
                    _societySpinnerLayout.Typeface = RegularFont;
                    _societySpinner.Typeface = RegularFont;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _societySpinnerLayout.Typeface = ItalicFont;
                _societySpinner.Typeface = ItalicFont;
            }

        }
```

I have tried with above code.But sometime it's throwing out of bound exception.and it's not properly worked.Please give me solution to how to create floating spinner.

Comment: Just place a spinner in text input layout may be?

Comment: @G.hakim no it's not work

Comment: why not use spinner directly ?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this for a long while as I did a similar implementation in one of my earlier projects and then I remembered that I was using the [Ganfra Material Spinner](https://github.com/akamud/MaterialSpinner-Xamarin/blob/master/README.md) to achieve this:

There is a sample project available [here](https://github.com/akamud/MaterialSpinner-Xamarin/tree/master/sample)

You can use it in XML like below:

```
<fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
app:ms_multiline="false"
app:ms_hint="hint"
app:ms_enableFloatingLabel="false"
app:ms_enableErrorLabel="false"
app:ms_floatingLabelText="floating label"
app:ms_baseColor="@color/base"
app:ms_highlightColor="@color/highlight"
app:ms_errorColor="@color/error"
app:ms_typeface="typeface.ttf"
app:ms_thickness="2dp"
app:ms_hintColor="@color/hint"
app:ms_arrowColor="@color/arrow"
app:ms_arrowSize="16dp"
app:ms_alignLabels="false"
app:ms_floatingLabelColor="@color/floating_label"/>
```

You can set a hint and a floating label text. If no floating label text is provided, the hint will be set instead.

You use it like a regular spinner, setting an adapter to it:

```
string[] ITEMS = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6"};
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, ITEMS);
adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
var spinner = FindViewById<MaterialSpinner>(Resource.Id.spinner1);
spinner.Adapter = adapter;
```

If you need to set an error message, you can do it the same way as an `EditText`:

```
 // Activate
 spinner.Error = "Error";
 // Deactivate
 spinner.Error = null;
```

You can choose to have a scrolling animation or to set the error message on multiple lines with the `ms_multiline` attribute in XML (default is true).